# Applescript Illustrator error number - 1700 Can’t make end into type reference

Tags: applescript

I put this script together and it works but I'm getting the error number *- 1700 Can’t make end into type reference*. I suspect I have the tell blocks incorrect? Any advices appreciated.
Thanks in advance

```
tell application "Adobe Illustrator"

--(resize page) 
set newWidth to 17
set newWidthPoints to newWidth * 72 -- (1 inch = 72 points)
set newHeight to 22
set newHeightPoints to newHeight * 72 -- (1 inch = 72 points)
set artboard rectangle of artboard 1 of document 1 to {0.0, 0.0, newWidthPoints, -newHeightPoints}

--(make spots)
activate
tell document 1
    set docColorSpace to color space
    if (docColorSpace is CMYK) then
        set SpotColor1 to {cyan:21.0, magenta:0, yellow:100.0, black:0.0}
        set SpotColor2 to {cyan:11.0, magenta:100, yellow:30.0, black:0.0}
        set SpotColor3 to {cyan:0.0, magenta:0, yellow:0.0, black:100.0}
        set SpotColor4 to {cyan:75.0, magenta:0, yellow:100.0, black:0.0}
    else
        set SpotColor1 to {red:206.0, green:219.0, blue:41.0}
        set SpotColor2 to {red:215.0, green:23.0, blue:111.0}
        set SpotColor3 to {red:35.0, green:34.0, blue:33.0}
        set SpotColor4 to {red:57.0, green:181.0, blue:74.0}

    end if

    make new spot with properties {name:"Highlight White", color type:spot color, color:SpotColor1}
    make new spot with properties {name:"Under Base", color type:spot color, color:SpotColor2}
    make new spot with properties {name:"Spot Black", color type:spot color, color:SpotColor3}
    make new spot with properties {name:"Barrier Base", color type:spot color, color:SpotColor4}


    set rectProps to {fill color:"C=0 M=0 Y=0 K=0", stroke weight:0.5}

    --(New Layer)

    make new layer

    --(make guides)
    set Rectangle1 to make new rectangle with rectProps
    set width of Rectangle1 to 0
    set height of Rectangle1 to 1728
    set position of Rectangle1 to {324, 72}

    set Rectangle2 to make new rectangle with rectProps
    set width of Rectangle2 to 0
    set height of Rectangle2 to 1728
    set position of Rectangle2 to {612, 72}

    set Rectangle3 to make new rectangle with rectProps
    set width of Rectangle3 to 0
    set height of Rectangle3 to 1728
    set position of Rectangle3 to {900, 72}

    set Rectangle4 to make new rectangle with rectProps
    set width of Rectangle4 to 1368
    set height of Rectangle4 to 0
    set position of Rectangle4 to {-72, -72}

    set selection to every page item of layer 1
end tell
end tell
tell application "Adobe Illustrator"
activate
tell document 1
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "Illustrator"
            keystroke "5" using {command down}
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
end tell
end
```

Comment: There's an extra `end` keyword at the end of the code that you should get rid of, but the script works OMM (10.10, CS6) regardless. BTW, you don't need GUI Scripting to make guides in AI: just replace the `set selection...` line with `set guides of every page item of layer 1 to true`.

Comment: Awesome, Thank you!! I appreciate  the help. I looked all over the place for  that bit about the guides but kept finding the wrong thing. I cut the add spot color part out too and it compiled much better and doesn't return any errors.